# Should I use make_unique or reset() for already defined smart pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have a function that optionally allocates an object and returns it:

```
// Class member
std::deque<Packet> m_receiveQueue;

// Function in class that operates on the queue
template<typename T>
std::unique_ptr<T> Get()
{
  std::unique_ptr<T> response;

  if (!m_receiveQueue.empty())
  {
     response = std::make_unique<T>(m_receiveQueue.front());
     m_receiveQueue.pop();
  }

  return response;
}
```

Should I instead do:

```
response.reset(new T{m_receiveQueue.front()});
```

Why or why not? Also does the same advice apply to other smart pointers, such as `shared_ptr`? Just looking for a best practice.

Comment: `unique_ptr& operator=( unique_ptr&& r );` is effective the same with call `reset(r.release())` and copy/move its deleter

Comment: Why do you think this case is different than when you are creating a new pointer?

Comment: @ks1322 How can it be double deleted?

Comment: To me the assignment looks more natural and now you do not have a *naked new*

Comment: why not `return std::make_unique<T>(m_receiveQueue.pop())`?

Comment: @Caleth Most `pop` functions return `void`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Most? It's not even in the spec. Standard says pop returns void: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/pop

Comment: @void.pointer I'm not sure what container they OP is using,  It may be a custom one.  AFAIK all standard containers return void on pop but I used most since it might not be a standard container.

Comment: @NathanOliver Good point; I have updated my code example to show the type of the queue.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Don't do it, use the `std::make_unique` one.

If I were to look at your code, and see a call to `reset`, I might wonder what pointer the smart pointer was referring to before, and try to find the code where you change ownership of that pointer. But the smart pointer is empty in your case!

That's weird, why would you call `reset` on a empty pointer, it is already empty/"reset". Try to code so that your intent is better and clear, in this case, even though both are technically equivalent in your case, use `std::make_unique`. It better describes what you are trying to do (initializing a new smart pointer, not changing the ownership of it).